# open command line in specific dir and execute command with processbuilder not working

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, processbuilder

I am trying to run command line from java. From java, the code should open a new cmd, change to specific dir (C:\EasyTest\4\bin) and run command (runTC 'testCase/test2.tc -c love -k ShinRamyun -logToConsole') from there. To do so, I tried several ways but not working.

```
String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "start", "runTC","testCase/test2.tc -c love -k ShinRamyun -logToConsole"};
     ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );


  probuilder.directory(new File("C:\\EasyTest\\4\\bin"));

       Process process = probuilder.start();
```

it returns opened cmd for 1 sec and exits directly. I couldn't see the result and the application which is executed by runTC is not affected.

the other way, I run

```
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd", "/c","start", "cd C:\\EasyTest\\4\\bin && runTC testCase/test2.tc -c love -k ShinRamyun -logToConsole\"" );
      processBuilder.start();
```

But it only launches cmd with title 'cd C:\EasyTest\4\bin && runTC testCase/test2.tc -c love -k ShinRamyun -logToConsole\' and dir of the project related

What I want is run 'runTC testCase/test2.tc -c love -k ShinRamyun -logToConsole' from specific dir from cmd

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think it should be `cmd.exe` instead of just `cmd`

Comment: I tried it but returns the same thing

Comment: first of all it's cmd.exe as pointed out already. and why are u using "/c"? this terminates the cmd window after executing your command

Comment: I put /c to display cmd. I also put cmd.exe but gives the same result

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```